# Acumatica - VisibleExp in PXTab with value contain space not working

Tags: acumatica

I work in screen Requests (RQ301000) and I want to hide a tab with the visibleExp property of the PXTab in Aspx.

The condition is : if the field edReqClassID (Request Class) equal "1FG INFO", the tab appears.

So I put `DataControls["edReqClassID"].Value==1FG INFO` in the visibleExp Field of the Aspx Tab but it doesn't work.

But when I try with edReqClassID equal "2AM" (`DataControls["edReqClassID"].Value==2AM`), it works.

So I think the problem is on the space caracter and I changed the space caracter by &nbsp in "1FG INFO" but still doesn't work.

Can you help me to show a tab with space in the value (1FG INFO).

Best,

Alexis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the view based on the dac can be completely hidden you can try setting AllowSelect equal to false. When the tab does not contain anything then by default it will be hidden. This also allows you to not have an special logic in the aspx file.

example:

```
MyView.AllowSelect = false;
```

You can set maybe in constructor on a setup table or rowselected of primary view/dac type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the value with the space work, as that might be tricky seeing the   did not work; An ulterior solution would be to create an unbound boolean field in the DAC which you can hardcode the getter of the property. Then add that field to the UI and set it Visible false from the layout editor/aspx instead of using the PXUIFieldAttribute. In the visibleExpr of the tab use the control bound with the unbound checkbox. This should have the same effect, although the downside is, if you need to change the condition of the hidden tab you would need to recompile the code instead of just publishing the customization project.